# replace unknown number of values in a java strings

Tags: java, string

How do i replace multiple words with an empty string "" in a string with java. I tried with for loop to replace those in single quotes by adding then in an array like below, but it replaces one word per printout.

```
String str = "this house 'is' really 'big' and 'attractive'.";
String[] values={"is","big","attractive"};
for(String s: values){
    String replaced = str.replace(s, "");
    System.out.println( replaced );
}
```

I'm getting this output:

```
> this house ' ' really 'big' and 'attractive'.
> this house 'is' really ' ' and 'attractive'.
> this house 'is' really 'big' and ' '.
```

What I need is this:

```
> this house ' ' really ' ' and ' '.
```

Comment: Remius answer is correct, but if you want to make your code working replace "String replaced" with "str" (and thereby improve the result at every iteration) and move the println behind the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your approach is wrong**

Strings in Java are immutable - when you call replace , it doesn't change the contents of the existing string - it returns a new string with the modifications. So you want:

`str= str.replace(s, "");` instead of `String replaced = str.replace(s, "");`

Also, write this code after the for loop: `System.out.println(str);` and omit `System.out.println( replaced );` as its placement is inside the for loop right now resulting into multiple statements getting printed.

Note that after doing all this, code would print `th house '' really '' and ''.` and NOT the desired output.

**Why follow Reimeus's answer OR use a generic regex expression**

Even after correcting your code, you would NOT get the desired results, hence :)

Answer (score 6):

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("is|big|attractive", ""));
```

Comment: `String.join("|", values)` could help to get the regex from the array.

Answer (score 1):

You re-start each iteration from the original `String`, which you don't modify.

You could change the `String` your `str` refers to and use that, like this:

```
      for(String s: values){
             str = str.replace(s, "");
             System.out.println( str );
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-initializing`replaced` in every iteration. So you end up with a string in which only the last element of array `values` is replaced.
To get the desired output, try this:

```
String replaced =  str;
for(String s: values){
    replaced = replaced.replace(s, "");
}
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all. String replaced = s; will cause a Compilation error

Comment: Rookie mistake. Corrected! :)

Comment: so why do you need the 'replaced' variable at all? just replacing replaced by str would do the trick ;)

Comment: OP used a seperate variable for output. So I did the same.
(This is my first ever answer on SO. Lot to learn :D )

Comment: But even this approach won't produce the desired output.

Comment: and why not? because he hasn't added the print statement, or do you see something wrong?

Comment: OP need the following output: "this house ' ' really ' ' and ' '". . Following my solution (yours too), the output will be: "th house '' really '' and '' ".